# Get year with custom php function

Tags: php

I have a custom php function which looks like this:

```
<select name="year" class="form-control">
  <?php echo dropDownnumbers(1910, 1999, "1983"); ?>
</select>
```

Entire function can be found here: 
[Dropdown function](http://pastebin.com/t6Kdp5Rz)

What function does is that it creates a drop down list with dates from 1910 to1999 and select automatically 1983 when page is loaded. 
So far this works fine.

Now i would like to add another function to this where i want to replace 1999 with minimum 18 years from now.

```
<?php
     //count minimum 18 years backward
     $years18 = date('Y', strtotime('-18 years'));
?>

<select name="year" class="form-control">
<?php echo dropDownnumbers(1910, $years18, "1983"); ?>
</select>
```

But for some reason it doesn't want to display the numbers now.. Any ideas why?

Comment: We need to see your function

Comment: http://pastebin.com/t6Kdp5Rz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to cast the result from `date()` to `int` because `date()` returns a `string`.

So change to:

```
 $years18 = intval(date('Y', strtotime('-18 years')));
```

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can see from your example is that the end date is being passed in as a variable as a string but the one that works passes an integer. 
Try changing the string to an integer.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: I can't comment until reputation 50.
I've updated my paragraph to apply a more assertive answer. I did actually answer their question by suggesting the integer/string issue but didn't show an example of it. I'm learning - thanks.